# How to replace Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler in web.config with patch file

Tags: configuration

how to replace the existing media request handler with custom one in web.config with help of patch file,

existing handler in web.config:

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler"/>
```

my custom handler:

```
<add verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="demo.Foundation.Sitecore.ExtendedMediaRequest.ExtendedMediaRequestHandler, demo.Foundation.Sitecore.ExtendedMediaRequest" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do this with patch files. Patch files are for sitecore config only. You can use slowcheetah transforms https://www.google.com/search?q=slowcheetah+transforms

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible with patch files. You can use a patch file to customize the Sitecore configuration only. It means, it only patches what is inside the

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can read more about patching

- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/customizing_server_configuration/use_a_patch_file_to_customize_the_sitecore_configuration
- https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/customizing_server_configuration/configuration_patch_file_examples

For the `web.config` parts which are outside of the `<sitecore>` node, you can use `Slowcheetah Transforms` during your build and publish process ( https://www.google.com/search?q=slowcheetah+transforms ).

Answer (score 0):

I always like to take opportunities like this to remind developers to never directly modify the web.config. This make upgrades more difficult. Always transform a new web.config out of the Sitecore default web.config.

For the request above, use this slowcheetah transform

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="demo.Foundation.Sitecore.ExtendedMediaRequest.ExtendedMediaRequestHandler, demo.Foundation.Sitecore.ExtendedMediaRequest" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```